# How to change php version to 7.0.33?

Tags: php, ubuntu, version, php-7

I cant seem to figure out how to change php version on ubuntu to 7.0.33.. If i Install 70, it goes past 7.0.33.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/353550/how-to-install-old-php-version

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/109404/how-do-i-install-different-upgrade-or-downgrade-php-version-in-still-supported